# Saber cuando un text area tiene únicamente espacios en blanco

Tags: javascript, regex, condiciones

Cómo sería la expresión regular a aplicar para que en un textarea, si escribes unicamente espacios en blanco, no te lo valide?

Ahora mismo tengo la condición de que no valide el textarea si no se ha escrito nada, es decir:

```
if (textarea === ''){}
```

Comment: Con solo utilizar la funcion trim ya lo tienes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como te comentan podrías utilizar simplemente `trim()`:

```js
function validar(){
  let str = document.getElementById("textarea");
  if (str.value.trim() === ""){
    console.log("El input tiene sólo espacios en blanco");
  }
  else{
    console.log("El input NO tiene sólo espacios en blanco");
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" rows="4" cols="50">
</textarea>
<input id="btnValidar" type="button" value="Validar" onclick="validar()"/>
```

O bien utilizar una `Regex`:

```js
function validar(){
  let str = document.getElementById("textarea");
  if (new RegExp("^\\s+$").test(str.value)){
    console.log("El input tiene sólo espacios en blanco");
  }
  else{
    console.log("El input NO tiene sólo espacios en blanco");
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" rows="4" cols="50">
</textarea>
<input id="btnValidar" type="button" value="Validar" onclick="validar()"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Comprobar el contenido de una caja de texto (y otros tipos de campos de texto) es realmente frecuente, entonces para evitar repetir código de validación cada vez que lo necesites, puedes usar una función que evalúe si el contenido de tu caja de texto (o cualquier otro control que sirva para ingresar texto) es NULL (no se escribió nada) o solo caracteres en blanco:

```
public static boolean isNullOrBlank(String textoEnviado) {
    return (s == null || s.trim().equals(""));
}
```

Donde *textoEnviado* sería el contenido de tu caja de texto